# Reorder the atoms in the POSCAR file

Tags: vasp

I want to rearrange the order of the atoms in the POSCAR file, is there any software able to do this? For example, in the below POSCAR file, I want to put Ti atoms before others.

````
TiO2_mp-390_primitive_geo_opt (1 0 1)-pseudoH_opt_supercell-fix-1 
1.0 
10.518000 -3.881298 0.000000 
0.000000 7.762594 0.000001 
0.000000 0.000000 25.587641 
H C O Ti Pt 
4 4 48 24 1 
Selective Dynamics
Direct 
0.368202 0.184099 0.117556 F F F 
0.868201 0.184099 0.117556 F F F 
0.368202 0.684099 0.117556 F F F 
0.868201 0.684099 0.117556 F F F 
0.108065 0.054035 0.118569 F F F 
0.608065 0.054035 0.118569 F F F 
0.108065 0.554036 0.118569 F F F 

```
````

Comment: +1 but can you be more specific? What reordering do you want to do?

Comment: @NikeDattani, I just update the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`atomsk` can sort atoms based on **atomic weight**.

```
atomsk POSCAR -sort species down pos
```

short trick is whichever element you want to be at top, make sure its name in `POSCAR` should have highest **atomic weight**. In your case, you want $\ce{Ti}$ at the top which have lower atomic weight than $\ce{Pt}$, hence I will replace $\ce{Ti}$ by $\ce{U}$ in `POSCAR` and run the above command.After generating `POSCAR`, I will change $\ce{U}$ by $\ce{Ti}$ again. This is not the best method but it works.